# Attribute selector on image fails in IE7

Tags: css, css-selectors, internet-explorer-7, html

When trying to target an image based on it's width attribute value it works in all versions of IE except version 7.

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/mGcE5/

Anyone got the same experience or explanation?

Comment: Obviously IE7 is doing *something* with the attribute value, since selecting by this works: `img[width]` This also works: `img[width*="3"]` Heck, even this matches it, when [it's not supposed to](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-substrings) `img[width*=""]` But then this doesn't work: `img[width*="2"]` Neither does this: `img[width*="0"]`

Comment: No explanation but it´s a known issue: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/attributeselector#compatibilitysection

Comment: It is known that IE7 has trouble with attribute selectors in general, but the SitePoint Reference doesn't mention `width` attributes in particular. I don't think it's quite related to DOM properties vs HTML attributes as I cannot get the selector to pick up any of the DOM properties corresponding to that attribute.

Comment: Man this pisses me off. It is actually useful to select images by width. To determine what layout to use. But then again, in most cases IE7 can live with a different (simpler) layout.

Comment: If you're looking for a workaround, you could change those `width` attributes to `data-width` (and run a quick Javascript routine that cycles through all images with a `data-width` attribute and sets their `style.width` accordingly). That way, the CSS works. On IE8 in IE7 compatibility mode at least; can't check with the real IE7.

Answer (score 0):

IE7 have buggy support for this selectors: `[attr]`, `+`, `:first-child` (but stable for `.class1.class2`, `>` and `~`)

So if you want stable support for this selector in IE7 -> the only way to use same jQuery selector